# Visual Studio 2015 installation issue - SqlDom_amd64\SqlDom.msi

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015, however, after several steps, Installer pops up one message as below,

[image]

I cleared %temp% files however,it did not work either yet. It is not package issue because that this package was installed successfully in another WIN7 system.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The real problem is that your windows is missing some Microsoft certificates, to verify if this is the case:

1. Open certification manager (Win+R -> certmgr.msc)
2. Go to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" -> "Certificates"
3. Check for:

   - "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority"
   - "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010"
   - "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011".
   - You most likely don't have all of them from some reason.

On other PC that is connected to the internet and receiving Microsoft updates:

1. Check again for these certificates, you most likely see them.
2. Export them to SST file.
3. Import the SST file (that contain the 3 certificates) in the first PC.

Install again, now it will work :-)

I believe that this will also fix some Visual Studio 2013 SDKDDKVer.h and related errors.

Comment: This also works for fixing the same issue when installing Visual studio remote debugger.

Comment: This helped to solve the issue for installing VS2015 in a offline PC.

Comment: On windows 7 or any other version if root certification authority is expired use below link o find the updated certifcate, install to resolver the issue..
https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem yesterday only and didn't found the exact solution but some work-arounds that did the job. 
I faced issues in installing following components using vs_community.exe:-
 - SqlDom_amd64
 - TSqlLanguageService
 - CT/AzureMobileServicesSdkV2.0
 - Win10_UniversalCRTSDK
     - Headers Libraries and sources
 - WcfDataServices
 - Win81_SDK
 - SQLSysClrTypes
 - SQLSysClrTypes_amd64
 - SharedManagementObjects_x86
 - SharedManagementObjects_amd64

TRICK:
 - Since, choosing the location that has that package didn't help so I clicked SKIP PACKAGE-option for all packages listed above. 
 - And, then manually ran set-up/msi-installers for above listed packages. 
 - Some got successfully installed like 'SqlDom_amd64' and few others 
 - But to my bad luck, for some it was kind of crashing during extraction so I thought msi-installer might actually got corrupted for some. 
 - So, for the left ones, I've to choose 'Repair'-option of 'vs_community.exe' and opt for 'Download packages from Internet'.
 - Finally, set-up got successful and everything is working fine.

I understand its a work-around and not a solution but it serves the purpose with a limitation that it needs internet-connection for some packages.

Comment: Your answer should be a solution for now. Since I follow the same steps as you mentioned, at least VS 2015 could be launched after installation. But not sure whether there is any potential risk would break current vs process. Anyway, you resolved my issue. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Download first sqldom manually and al the other packages will be downloaded automatically.