# .exe has triggered a breakpoint while remote debugging

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I can't debug ANY (even newly created and empty) `CPP` project in `Visual Studio 2015` with remote debugger if remote system is `Windows 2008 R2`. It is always a exception after the attach:

> .exe has triggered a breakpoint

I've installed standalone `rdb tools` and some system updates, but get the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @xaxxon i mean that if you faced that problem you can understand the question, there is nothing special to add. Its look like a bug in a remote debugger

Comment: Triggering a breakpoint is not an exception. You have the debugger attached—where is the breakpoint being triggered? What code is triggering it? If your question is, is there a fatal bug in Visual Studio 2015 that prevents the use of remote debugging for C++ applications, then the answer is of course no. It works fine on my machine, and plenty of other people's.

Comment: @CodyGray stackframe always is the same - 0x00000000771d0530(), no modules, no code, output is empty. My rdb tools works fine on my desktop, or any other machine, until i attached it to windows 2008 r2 station

Comment: If interesting, my problem goes to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156636/how-to-install-remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2015-on-machine-not-connected-to-t) - at first i could not install rdb tools with same errorcode - `0x800b010a`.

Answer (score 0):

`Remote Debugger Tools 2015 Update 3` can not be installed correctly on our `WS2008R2` with error `0x800b010a`, so i have installed it on other machine and then copy it back to those servers. After that remote debugger works fine, and i think it is a some kind of bug in msvsmon version, which comes with my Visual Studio Distribution